# How to change size of caption font while I use hang format?

Tags: floats, captions, fontsize

I hope you are doing well. I have tried to change the font size of the caption by

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\fontsize{8}{6}\selectfont#1#2#3}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}
```

but I have lost hang format and I have got something like this:

> ```
> Fig. 1. caption caption caption
> caption caption caption caption
> ```

while I want something like this:

> ```
> Fig. 1. caption caption caption
>         caption caption caption
> ```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Assuming that you use `caption` package, you can define font size with  `\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}` fo example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own font commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{myfont}{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont}
\captionsetup{format=hang,font=myfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
text text
\caption[toc]{hang hang hang\\hang hang hang}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Side remark: the second number in the fontsize argument should always be larger than the first, it describes the distance of the lines.